# Aesthetic math books that are written in LaTeX that are open source

Tags: books

I found this book called [linear algebra done right](http://ce.sharif.edu/courses/97-98/1/ce425-1/resources/root/Books/Linear%20Algebra%20Done%20Right.pdf) and I was shocked at how the book looks. I tried to find the LaTeX code for it, but it isn't open source.

Could anyone point me to other books that look like linear algebra done right, but they're open source?

Thanks

-- ART

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a package, font, tool, book or other off-site resource** are off-topic as they usually do not revolve around an abstract issue.  Instead, [describe the problem](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and what has been done so far to solve it or, if applicable, ask on [Software Recommendations SX](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: It appears to be a special version made for screen viewing, not print: small margin and large font that fits nicely on one half of the screen displaying a full page and leaving room for a text editor on the other half. I like it.

Comment: [*Linear Algebra*](https://hefferon.net/linearalgebra/) by Jim Hefferon is one such.

Comment: Hmm, is _that_ Axler book really supposed to be frealy available? I did not know. (The earlier edition looks nicer in my opinion, but that is another thing.) (I see nothing about it being freely availble here: https://linear.axler.net/)

Comment: Maybe that university has rights to put the book online, but it's quite certainly illegal for you to download it.

Comment: @egreg Yes the book (of Jim Hefferon) is freely downloadable.

Comment: @RaffaeleSantoro I was referring to the book linked in the question

Comment: @egreg It looks like this book is #159 in the list of free books from Springer linked by this announcement: https://www.springernature.com/gp/librarians/the-link/blog/blogposts-ebooks/free-access-to-a-range-of-essential-textbooks/17855960

Answer (score 3):

Look at this web site:
https://joshua.smcvt.edu/linearalgebra/

You have pdf and LaTeX source code. You can find also answers book.

Comment: I looked into the source code for this book. What are the other languages that he used to create this book? Like `sage` and `asymptote`?

Comment: I dont know. I look only at pdf file.

Comment: @RaffaeleSantoro -- The book is by Jim Hefferon.  Look at [this page](https://hefferon.net/jimhefferon.html) to find his email address.  I'm sure he's be willing to answer your question.

Comment: @barbara beeton. Yes I answered. I know this book from a lot of years.  Differents editions.

Comment: @SingularisArt sage, https://www.sagemath.org/ is a Computer Algebra System. Asymptote is a graphic language included in several TeX distributions, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptote_(vector_graphics_language)